# Symfony - parameters.yml return data

Tags: php, symfony, parameters

I have configured this params..

```
w2:
  wsdl: "some link"
  sandbox: true
  api_key: c6480d13-e0a5-4c52-b0a9-dd4e87e9b074
```

I need to write a statement that when the sandbox is true to return this data..

```
$options = [

        'KeyValue' => [
            [
                'Key' => 'Sandbox',
                'Value' => 'true',
            ]
        ],
    ];
```

and when it's false

```
 $options = [

        'KeyValue' => [
            [

            ]
        ],
    ];
```

I don't know how to include defined param from .yml file in the function I have to write.

I tried this one but I think that's not the solution..

```
if ( $this->container->getParameter('w2')['sandbox'] = 1){

    $queryOptions = [

        'KeyValueOfstringstring' => [
            [
                'Key' => 'Sandbox',
                'Value' => 'true',
            ]
        ],
    ];

    }else $queryOptions = [

        'KeyValueOfstringstring' => [
            [

            ]
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: and `if(...)` statement should always at least contain TWO `=` equal signs for comparison not only one

Comment: Thank you. Is mine syntax correct?

Comment: Start here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the sandbox parameter inside parameters.yml? If so, you can take the value this way in the Controller: `$this->getParameter('sandbox')`. But your parameters.yml should be this way:

```
parameters:
    sandbox: true
```

Although we usually put in parameters.yml params like: database name, api keys, urls that 
would be different locally and in production enviroment. Just keep that in mind.